# Changing SUM to count elements of array twice in YugabyteDB YSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I have an SQL related question.I have a query like this:

```
SELECT SUM("baseOccupancy")
        FROM "RoomTypes"
        WHERE id IN (134,134)
```

Now each `baseOccupany` is `2` and what I want is `4` but since both `ids` inside `IN` array are the same, it's just returning `2` instead of `4`.
Can anyone help me write a query where the query runs for each `id` inside the array inside the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
select sum("baseOccupancy")
from "RoomTypes"
,unnest(array[134,134]) myListOfId
where id = myListOfId
```

But knowing what is the root problem you want to solve may bring a better solution.
Because a where clause is the to filter table rows, not to de-multiply them.

The principal misunderstanding here seems to be what `SUM()` and `COUNT()` are doing.
`COUNT()` counts the number of rows, regardless of the value inside the column it's set to count.
`SUM()` reads inside the set column and adds up the values. That makes both principally different.
Therefore, if rows are using a unique id, a `COUNT()` of two id's that exist and have a value for `baseOccupancy` will result in 2. A `SUM()` of these will be the total of the two fields.